# USB external drive is not recognized by any OS, how to troubleshoot in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, external-hdd, usb-drive, dmesg

First of all I would like to inform you that I saw a question similar to mine but the error was different, so here's my problem...

I have an external HD samsung s2 model of 500GB and a day to day just stopped working, tried in other systems (windows and mac) however are not recognized. In the windows device manager when I insert the usb it states that the device in question are not working properly.

Well, in the logs of my ubuntu 4.12 I see the following message when I insert my usb device in:

```
[ 2967.560216] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[ 2967.680182] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2967.904176] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2968.120227] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[ 2968.240207] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2968.464063] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2968.680087] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[ 2969.092085] usb 7-2: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[ 2969.208155] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[ 2969.624076] usb 7-2: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[ 2969.624118] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[ 4520.240340] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[ 4520.364079] usb 7-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4520.588109] usb 7-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4520.804140] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd
[ 4520.924136] usb 7-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4521.148083] usb 7-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4521.364105] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd
[ 4521.776237] usb 7-1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[ 4521.888206] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using uhci_hcd
[ 4522.296102] usb 7-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[ 4522.296150] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 4749.036104] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd
[ 4749.156209] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4749.380215] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4749.596206] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using uhci_hcd
[ 4749.716409] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4749.940110] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4750.156257] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using uhci_hcd
[ 4750.572150] usb 7-2: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[ 4750.684215] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using uhci_hcd
[ 4751.100182] usb 7-2: device not accepting address 13, error -71
[ 4751.100224] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

Here is my system:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 08ff:2810 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2810

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev ba)
02:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
02:01.2 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 21)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5756ME Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Does anyone have any clue what would be the problem?

Comment: Does your Pc have Earthing , [Here](http://paulphilippov.com/articles/how_to_fix_device_not_accepting_address_error) it says , Unplug all USB devices from PC, turn power off, and wait a minute or two. Plug everything back and boot into Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the USB controller chip in the hard-drive box appears to have failed. Not Ubuntu or Windows or Mac can recognize it as you said.

You can try to open and extract the hard drive if you want to rescue any data on it since that appears to be okay.